# Guardar imagen en Firebase con una funcion y retorne un Map<String, Object>

Tags: android, firebase, android-layout, firebase-messaging, firebase-auth

Colaboreme con este problema por favor: hice una función con la intención de guardar la imagen, pero me doy cuenta que fuera del `onSucces()` del `mImageProvider.save()` el map o si fuera una variable su valor es `null`; pero si imprimo la variable o el mapa dentro del `onSucces()`, si tiene el valor asignado.

**metodo donde  invoco la funcion guardar imagen:**

```
  private void savePost(final String title, final String description) {                 
     
        Post post = new Post();
        post.setIdUser(mAuthProvider.getUid());

         /***********AQUI INVOCO LA FUNCION GUARDAR 
        IMAGEN***************************/  
        Map<String, Object> map = saveImagen_1();
        post.setImage1((String) map.get("url_image_1"));
     
        post.setTitle(title);
        post.setDescription(description);
        post.setCategory(mCategory);
     
        mPostProvider.save(post).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> taskSave) {
                if(taskSave.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Post guardado correctamente", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

//FUNCION GUARDAR IMAGEN

```
private Map<String, Object> saveImagen_1(){
    final Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    mImageProvider.save(PostActivity.this, mImageFile_1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                mImageProvider.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
 
                        String url = uri.toString();
                        map.put("estado", true);
                        map.put("url_image_1", url);

                      /*******QUI IMPRIME CORRECTO LOS VALORES DEL MAP*********/   
                        Log.i("imagen", "map: "+map.get("url_image_1"));
 
                    }
                });
            }else{
                map.put("estado", false);
                map.put("url_image_1", "");
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error al subir la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
 
    /************************************************
AQUI IMPRIME NUUL EL MAP
**************************************/
    Log.i("imagen", "map: "+map.get("url_image_1"));
    return map;
}
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda, feliz día!!

Comment: ¿Qué mensaje se imprime primero?

Comment: @jachguate gracias por preguntar, hice la prueba y primero se imprimio el ultimo log osea el de afuera, y despues el log que esta dentro del  onSuccess() ... osea que se esta haciendo el return antes que se complete el mImageProvider.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener()...

Comment: Y esa es la razón por la que el de afuera se imprime vacío, porque es hasta que la llamada retorna (cuando se llama a onSuccess, que la asignación se ha llevado a cabo.

Comment: Si es correcto, y como se puede hacer para el return no se devuelva vacio null?

Comment: ¿De qué clase es la variable `mImageProvider`?

Comment: mImageProvider es  el provider que se encarga de subir la imagen al storage de firebase.  En el constructor de mImageProvider tengo la instancia de FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase trabaja de forma asíncrona, significa que si asignas un objeto que dependa de cualquier listener de Firebase, la asignación puede ocurrir sin que la llamada se haya completado y por tanto el objeto sea null, que es lo que ocurre.

De todos modos en tu código no aparece lo que quieres con `map` una vez haya ocurrido la llamada a Firebase. Si necesitas hacer algo con los datos que recibes de Firebase, lo que se hace generalmente es llamar a otro método **desde dentro del `onSuccess`**.

O sea, algo así, fuera de los métodos:

```
private Map<String, Object> map;
```

Ese objeto ya no lo crearías en `savePost()`, allí simplemente llamas al método que invoca a Firebase y llena a `map`:

```
private void savePost(final String title, final String description) {
     
        /***********AQUI INVOCO LA FUNCION GUARDAR IMAGEN***************************/  
        saveImagen_1();

        /*Resto del código*/
}
```

Y el método no retornará nada, llenará el Map (declarado como miembro de la clase) dentro de él, así no tendrás problemas de asincronía. El método debe ser declarado `void`. Si,luego de la llamada a Firebase necesitas operar con los datos obtenidos, lo propio es llamar a un método **desde dentro**, es la forma de asegurarte que se operará con los datos cuando la llamada a Firebase haya finalizado.

El método puede quedar así:

```
private void saveImagen_1(){
    map = new HashMap<>();
    mImageProvider.save(PostActivity.this, mImageFile_1).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                mImageProvider.getStorage().getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
 
                        String url = uri.toString();
                        map.put("estado", true);
                        map.put("url_image_1", url);

                      /*******QUI IMPRIME CORRECTO LOS VALORES DEL MAP*********/   
                        Log.i("imagen", "map: "+map.get("url_image_1"));
                        llamarMetodoQueUsaraLosDatos();
 
                    }
                });
            }else{
                map.put("estado", false);
                map.put("url_image_1", "");
                llamarMetodoQueUsaraLosDatos();
                Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Error al subir la imagen", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
 
    /************************************************
AQUI IMPRIME NUUL EL MAP
**************************************/
    Log.i("imagen", "map: "+map.get("url_image_1"));
}
```

Este sería el método para trabajar con `map`, si fuera necesario:

```
private void llamarMetodoQueUsaraLosDatos() {
    /*Aquí puedes trabajar con map que ya fue llenado en saveImagen_1()*/
    /*map es miembro de la clase y lo tendrás por tanto disponible*/
}
```

La clave es: **encadenar las llamadas desde dentro de los eventos de Firebase, no desde fuera**. Aún así queda una pequeña laguna en tu método `savePost`, pues allí haces también una llamada a Firebase. Si es posible, es mejor que la llamada a `saveImagen_1()` esté al final, cuando hayas terminado de trabajar con todas las operaciones que necesitas hacer en `savePost()`. Así organizas el código de una forma más clara:

1. Operar con Post;
2. Operar como Imagen;
3. Desde dentro de 2 llamar a un eventual método, si necesitas trabajar con la información obtenida en 2.

Comment: Para aclarar un poco: lo que hace el método savePost() es guardar una publicación  de un usuario en la base de datos de firestore. Pero esa publicacion contiene una imagen. Lo que hago es primero subir la imagen al storage de firestore con la funcion saveImagen_1() y retorne la url de esa imagen para añardirla al objeto post. Por ultimo cuando tengo los datos completos guardo el post asi: mPostProvider.save(post) .. Me gusto el orden que propones, muchas gracias

Comment: A. Cedano, la url que retorna saveImagen_1(), la necesito en savePost(), para guardar el post, Como me recomiendas organizar el código?

Comment: @roca33scorpio el orden propuesto fue en base a lo que tenías escrito, pero no significa que tenga que ser así estrictramente. Si primero necesitas la imagen, entonces cambia el orden: 1. Guardar la imagen; 2. Desde dentro del listener de Firebase llamar a `savePost`; 3. Guardar el post... Como el Map será miembro de la clase, lo tendrás disponible al momento de crear el Post, podrás recuperar la url de la imagen o lo que sea y usarlo para guardar el Post